# How to pass a pointer through a function that operates on the pointer with a non-pointer argument?

Tags: c++, pointers, codeblocks

I am just starting to learn C++ on Code::Blocks and am doing an exercise with dynamic memory allocation via the new and delete operators. The main function allows the user to request memory for multiple elements and then assign values to those elements/memory locations. I wanted to make a separate function, void sum(int pntsize, int* pnt), that when called allows the user to find the sum of the values assigned. Since the values are assigned via pointers, I am having trouble creating that function. When I go to compile the program there are no errors. However, no matter the values inputted or the number of elements created, the sum always returns as 1. While there are no errors, Code::Blocks gives a warning stating, "the address of 'void sum(int,int*)' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]", and I expect that this has to do with the problem I am encountering. Below is the r

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sum(int pntsize, int* pnt)
{
    for(int i=0; i<pntsize; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        sum = *(pnt+i) + sum;
    }
    cout << "The sum of these values is: " << sum;
}

int main()
{

for (char userinput2 = 'y'; userinput2 == 'y';)
            {cout << "For how many elements do you wish to reserve memory?" << endl; 
            int pntsize = 1;
            cin >> pntsize;
            cout << endl;
            int* pnt = new int [pntsize];
            for (int i=0; i<pntsize; i++) //Assigns values
            {
                cout << "Enter a value for Memory Slot " << i << ": ";
                cin >> *(pnt + i);
            }

            cout << endl;

            for (int i2=0; i2<pntsize; i2++) //Displays values
            {
                cout << "Value at Memory Location " << &(pnt[i2]) << ": " << *(pnt + i2) << endl;
            }
cout << endl;
cout << "Do you wish to find the sum of these values?" << endl; //Adds values
            char userinput3;
            cin >> userinput3;

            if (userinput3 == 'y')
                sum(pntsize, pnt);
return 0;
}
}
```

Maybe the warning has nothing to do with my problem, but maybe someone could explain why this problem keeps arising.

Comment: The variable `sum` goes out of scope when `cout << "The sum of these values is: " << sum;` is executed. It tries to print the function.

Answer (score 2):

You are redeclaring sum in your for loop. So at each iteration it will get re-initialzed to zero. Try:

```
void sum(int pntsize, int* pnt)
{
    int res = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<pntsize; i++)
    {
        res = *(pnt+i) + res;
    }
    cout << "The sum of these values is: " << res;
}
```

Btw, sum was actually referring to the actual function sum() when you cout'ed it, as the int had gone out of scope. I assume that is the reason you were getting this warning.

Comment: You can also do res += pnt[i], with the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

`cout<<"The sum of these values is: " << sum;` <- `sum` resolves to the name of the function. You probably meant to use the local variable inside the for loop. But it's not visible outside the scope(`{}`) it's declared. Also your way does not acumulate anything as the variable is created, initialized and destroyed on each iteration.
Fix:

```
void sum(int pntsize, int* pnt)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<pntsize; i++)
    {  
        sum = *(pnt+i) + sum;
    }
    cout << "The sum of these values is: " << sum;
}
```

Also please don't use `new`, use `std::unique_ptr`. Why? Because you already forgot to delete it.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem and got rid of the warning!